# How to trace a "ExpatParser$ParseException at line 1 column 0 no element found?

Tags: android, saxparser

As the question states I would like to know how to trace the cause of such a error.

During my research on this error I found various things using a inputstream. When it is called twice it gives the exception. However my code is not anything similar to those. I use a AndroidSaxParser inside a ViewPager. Each fragment executes a AsyncTask which parse a rss and loads the data into a ListView.

The problem occures at random times which makes it so difficult to trace what the problem causes. I also noticed that on a api 14+ device the problem doesn't occur at all. It only occurs at my api 8 device and probably at other devices < api 14.

The exact Expat error I get is :

```
ExpatParser$ParseException at line 1 column 0 no element found
```

The code at which the LogCat points is simply the code which starts the parser however nothing is null or different from times it does execute correctly.

```
    try
    {
        Xml.parse(this.getInputStream(), Xml.Encoding.UTF_8, root.getContentHandler());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("parser", "PARSER CRASHED");
        Log.e("expat", "inputStream " + this.getInputStream() + " xml " + Xml.Encoding.UTF_8 + " contentHandler " + root.getContentHandler());
        Log.w("the feed", "" + rssFeed);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

The trace :
[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQoNb.png)

Answer (score 5):

The inputStream you are using is empty when you are parsing it.First read the whole inputStream and then parse the content.